# How do I get a background banner image to work in ASP.NET MVC4 using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using a bootswatch, bootstrap CSS file in my ASP.NET MVC4 web project in VS 2012 and am having major difficulties getting a banner in the header to work with a background image.  How do I get a background image to appear?

I have tried creating a new class with a background image in the batsrap.css file like so:

```
      .banner > img {
           background-image: url(../images/webbanner.jpg);
           background-repeat: no-repeat;
           background-position: top center;
           background-size: cover;
           ......
```

When i do it this way, I get no image and everything else renders correctly.
I have also tried simply placing the image in a div in the HTML like so:

```
      <div class="navbar-header">
           <img src="~/images/webbanner.jpg" />
           .....
```

When I do it this way I get a tiny box with an "x" and everything else renders correctly.
I am using the "Simplex" css file from BootSwatch [here](http://bootswatch.com/simplex/).  I am using the example HTML for the default navbar.

Comment: Sounds like your not passing in the correct file path.

Comment: Is your image located at `root folder/images/webbanner.jpg`?

Comment: Yes, that is where it is at.  When I add it to the css file, as in my first example and I hover over the url("") it previews the correct banner image.  But it won't show up in the browser when I render.

Comment: Obviously something's messed up with your paths. when you drop your image in markup there shouldn't be an X if the image is found. Try using browser dev tools to see whether the image was loaded.

Comment: When I use the debug feature on VS 2012, it isn't letting EI10's debug feature work at the same time. I'm having trouble tracing anything.  I am trying to get VS 2013 and use weblink, but it is on a stand-alone, no0web access machine and i can't get it to install.  I've been working with Microsoft for 2 weeks on this and they can't figure it out.  I am getting the 0x800boo3 error fail authenticode.  The ISO checksum was good and it installed on a web-connected machine.  This is driving me nuts.